# How do I create a view form its xtype and pass to push function of a navigation view

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've seen examples of the new NavigationView component in Sencha Touch.  How would I switch to another view based on using its xtype. The API docs seem to have omitted a useful example showing most common usage (i.e. using the xtype with creating a new view). Or am I missing something?

In their example: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View

They are using the reference 'view' to push a new view.
But my questions are:

1) If the view that has initially been navigated to is a result of an xtype load like so:

```
Ext.Viewport.add({xtype:'testnavview'});
```

then how do I then get a reference to it to push views onto it if its implicitly loaded using xtype from the originating controller?

2) how can then I then push views onto the navigation view using the xtype (see below?) ...

i.e. can I do something like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestNav', {
    extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
    alias: 'widget.testnavview',
    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'View 1',
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: "button",
                    text: "View1",
                    handler: function () {
                        console.log("handler view1");

                        this.push({ xtype: "View1" });

                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: "button",
                    text: "View2"
                },
                 {
                     xtype: "button",
                     text: "View3"
                 },
                 {
                     xtype: "button",
                     text: "View4"
                 }

                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve you navigation view by adding a reference to it in your controller :

```
refs: {
  navigationView: 'navigationview'
}
```

Then you get it anywhere in your controller like this :

```
this.getNavigationView().push({xtype: 'myPushedView'});
```

Comment: Not sure I understand this, the handler which is supposed to push the view in the example is within the view not the controller...

Comment: It's the same. The handler is a function that is called when the tap event is fired on the button. So setting the handler or adding a tap event listener is basically the same. Now, if you're building an app which uses the MVC architecture (which I recommend), you should separate the views from the logic, from the code. So the code executed when you tap the button should be written in a controller. Now in the Sencha Docs, it is just a small example which is why they didn't bother setting up a controller.

Comment: Ok, got this working thanks:) Any idea why though, the view that is pushed then appears underneath with the original navigation view tab bar still docked at the top?

Comment: I think I know why this is. The navigation view itself is holding the cards, so if I add views they are sub-views underneath the existing tool bar.